# Estimate difference $f(x)\,H(f(x)-M) - g(x)\, H(g(x)-M)$, with $H$ the Heaviside function and $M>0$ fixed, in terms of the difference $|f - g|$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, functions

Let $f,g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f,g \in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$.

Fix $M>0$ and let $H$ denote the Heaviside function. How can we estimate the difference 
$$f(x)\,H(f(x)-M) - g(x)\, H(g(x)-M)$$

in terms of the difference $|f - g|$?

Answer (score 0):

First observe that
$$
f(x)H(f(x)-M) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } f(x)<M,\\
f(x) & \text{ if } f(x)\ge M\end{cases}.
$$
This is a discontinuous map. Suppose $f(x) = M+\epsilon$ and $g(x) = M-\epsilon$.
Then 
$$
f(x)H(f(x)-M) -g(x)H(g(x)-M) = M+\epsilon - 0.
$$
This cannot be bounded by $f(x)-g(x) = 2\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks. Is it true instead that $|f(x)\,H(f(x)-M) - g(x)\, H(g(x)-M)| \ge C |f(x)-g(x)| + a$ with $a \ge 0$?